# C++ moodycamel concurrent queue - enqueue pointers

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, concurrent-queue

I am trying to use ConcurrentQueue to log items into a file on a separate thread:

https://github.com/KjellKod/Moody-Camel-s-concurrentqueue

This works:

```
// declared on the top of the file
moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue<MyType> q; // logger queue
. . .
int MyCallbacks::Event(MyType* p)
{
   MyType item = (MyType)*p;
   q.enqueue(item);
. . .
// pthread
void* Logger(void* arg) {

    MyType.item;

    while (true)
        if (!q.try_dequeue(item))
```

This doesnt (object appears to be corrupted after dequeue:

```
// declared on the top of the file
moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue<MyType*> q; // logger queue
. . .
int MyCallbacks::Event(MyType* p)
{
   MyType item = (MyType)*p;
   q.enqueue(&item);
. . .
// pthread
void* Logger(void* arg) {

    MyType* item;

    while (true)
        if (!q.try_dequeue(item))
```

also tried this in the `Event` - still doesnt work (the &newdata always prints same address):

```
auto newdata = std::move(data);
printf("  - pointers - new: %p old: %p\n", &newdata, &data);
q.enqueue(&newdata);
```

Am I doing it wrong or is it the queue doesnt support pointers?

Comment: If a template is written properly, it shouldn't matter what types you use. Pointers or non-pointers shouldn't matter, the behavior should be the same either way.

Comment: With that said, what is your problem with the queue? What happens when you use it? What is supposed to happen? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a [mre] or how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: Oh, after you do `q.enqueue(&item);` do the life-time of `item` end before you dequeue the pointer? Will the `item` object be destructed before you try to use the pointer? If that happens, to what object is the pointer really pointing? Remember that copying a pointer only copies the actual pointer, not the object it points to.

Comment: sorry I edited the code to be more realistic - i get pointer to item from 3rd party lib, I convert it to value and enqueue - works, if I pass pointer or if I try std::move and pass pointer - the dequeued object is corrupted.

Comment: *Will the item object be destructed* - I dont know. This C++11 memory sorcery is all new to me. How do I tell compiler I want to destruct it manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
int MyCallbacks::Event(MyType* p)
{
   MyType item = (MyType)*p;
   q.enqueue(&item);
```

have a major flaw: You enqueue a pointer to the ***local*** variable `item`.

As soon as the `Event` function returns, the life-time of `item` ends, and it is destructed. The pointer to it that you saved will be invalid. Dereferencing that invalid pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

There's no need to create a local copy here at all, you should be able to work with `p` directly instead, including adding it to the queue:

```
q.enqueue(p);
```

---

With that said, you don't need the cast in

```
MyType item = (MyType)*p;
```

The type of `*p` already *is* `MyType`. Generally speaking, when you feel the need to do a C-style cast like that you should take it as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

---

If you need a copy, why not create a new object to copy-initialize?

Like:

```
MyItem* item = new MyItem(*p);
q.enqueue(item);
```

You of course have to remember to `delete` the object once you're finished with it.

A better solution than using raw non-owning pointers would be using a smart pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue<std::unique_ptr<MyType>> q; // logger queue

// ...

q.enqueue(std::make_unique<MyItem>(*p));
```

Comment: No I have to copy it somehow - the 3rd party lib is going to reuse memory as soon as I return from the callback.  (I dont care if it is wrong - so far the "right" thing does not work for **me** - I switched from C/C++ 20 yrs ago and all the "right" things look to me a horrible nightmare). Can you help? it must be something very simple - copy an object and stuff it into a queue - should be dead simple. No?

Comment: @BoppityBop Added a solution to copy object using pointers.